# Array from php to html input to JS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Here's what i'm trying to accomplish. Insert an array from php into an HTML form and then have that array be pushed in a JS array.

PHP

```
        $proxiearray = array();             
        if($row7['attribute_0'] != NULL) { array_push($proxiearray,$row7['attribute_0']);}
        if($row7['attribute_1'] != NULL) { array_push($proxiearray,$row7['attribute_1']);}

        <input type="hidden" class="proxie_attributes" value="'.htmlspecialchars(json_encode($proxiearray)).'">
```

Now what i want with that is on uppon a certain task on the client side for my JS to take that aray and push it in another one.

JS

```
attributesArray[counter] = new Array();
if(proxiearray) { attributesArray[counter] = proxiearray; }
```

If i alert the array i get
`["1","4"],5,6`

This just pushed in the array the `["1","4"]` but what i would want it to push is have a result like
`1,4,5,6`

I know i could go with X amount of inputs although that is not a solution since i may have to use a bigger ammount of attributes in the future.

EDIT: The `alert` is on the `attributesArray`.
The `attributesArray[counter]` alert is `["1","4"]`

Comment: What is `counter` in `attributesArray[counter] = new Array();` ?

Comment: An array inside of the attributesArray. edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following;

```
if ($(this).find('div .proxie_attributes').length > 0) {
    var proxiearray = JSON.parse($(".proxie_attributes").val());
    attributesArray[counter] = new Array();
    if(proxiearray) { 
        attributesArray[counter] = proxiearray; 
    }   
}
```

Comment: `var proxiearray =  JSON.parse($(this).find('div .proxie_attributes').val());` but one problem, in case the `.proxie_attributes` doesn't exist for the product for some reason JS stops